# MySQL Error: Incorrect usage of UPDATE and LIMIT

Tags: mysql, sql-update

How can I correct this problem so that my MySQL code works correctly.

Here is my MySQL code that gives me the problem.

```
$q = "UPDATE users INNER JOIN contact_info ON contact_info.user_id = users.user_id SET active.users = NULL WHERE (email.contact_info = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $x) . "' AND active.users = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $y) . "') LIMIT 1";
$r = mysqli_query ($mysqli, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

Comment: Your query includes references to columns in tables 'active' and 'email', while those tables are not included in the statement.  Look at 'http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/update.html' for guidance on how to structure a multi-table update.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

As per the MySQL docs for [UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html):

> For the multiple-table syntax, UPDATE updates rows in each table named in table_references that satisfy the conditions. In this case, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used.

Comment: I suppose the docs actually mean to say "neither ORDER BY nor LIMIT can be used" because I attempted LIMIT without using ORDER BY and still encountered this error.

Answer (score 22):

**if you want to update multiple rows using limit in mysql...directly limit you cant use try like this****

```
UPDATE table_name SET name='test'
     WHERE id IN (
         SELECT id FROM (
             SELECT id FROM table_name 
             ORDER BY id ASC  
             LIMIT 0, 10
         ) tmp
     );
```

Comment: A subselect within an `IN()` is slow as **** and can lock a table like forever. Use `EXISTS()` instead.

Comment: Syntax error or access violation: 1235 This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL
  /ANY/SOME subquery'

Answer (score 5):

I know it is an old question but it is the first link when googling this error.
There is a workaround to solve this problem without performance issue (depending on your indexes) by using a derived table.

```
UPDATE table1 t1
JOIN (SELECT t1.id
    FROM table1 t1
    JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
        AND t2.some_criteria = 'some_value'
    WHERE t1.other_criteria = 'other_value'
    LIMIT 10000
) tmp ON tmp.id = t1.id
SET t1.field_to_update = 'new_value'
```

Because the LIMIT is inside the subquery, the join will match only the number of rows of the clause LIMIT. So the query will update only those rows.

Answer (score 4):

For the multiple-table syntax, `UPDATE` updates rows in each table named in
table_references that satisfy the conditions. In this case, `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`
cannot be used

Answer (score 1):

@Marc B provides the reason, why `update` normally can't work with `limit`.

And @Roopchand also provide a solution.

For people like me, who is trying to avoid turning off the `safe update mode`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28316067/1278112
This answer is quite helpful. It give an example

> UPDATE customers SET countryCode = 'USA'
>       WHERE country = 'USA';               -- which gives the error, you just write:
>
> UPDATE customers SET countryCode = 'USA'
>       WHERE (country = 'USA' AND customerNumber <> 0); -- Because customerNumber is a primary key you got no error 1175 any more.

And when I face `update` with the multiple-table syntax, it also worked.

What I want but would raise error code 1175.

```
UPDATE table1 t1
        INNER JOIN
    table2 t2 ON t1.name = t2.name 
SET 
    t1.column = t2.column
WHERE
    t1.name = t2.name;
```

The working edition

```
UPDATE table1 t1
        INNER JOIN
    table2 t2 ON t1.name = t2.name 
SET 
    t1.column = t2.column
WHERE
    (t1.name = t2.name and t1.prime_key !=0);
```

Which is really simple and elegant. Since the original answer doesn't get too much attention (votes), I post more explanation. Hope this can help others.