# Update column from another table in large mysql db (7 million rows)

Tags: mysql, large-data-volumes

### Description

I have 2 tables with the following structure (irrelevant columns removed):

```
mysql> explain parts;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| code        | varchar(32)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| slug        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| title       | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and

```
mysql> explain details;
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field             | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sku               | varchar(32)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| description       | varchar(700) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| part_code         | varchar(32)  | NO   | PRI |         |       |
+-------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Table `parts` contains 184147 rows, and `details` contains 7278870 rows.
The `part_code` column from `details` represents the `code` column from the `parts` table.
Since these columns are `varchar`, I want to add the column `id int(11)` to `parts`, and `part_id int(11)` to `details`. I tried this:

```
mysql> alter table parts drop primary key;
Query OK, 184147 rows affected (0.66 sec)
Records: 184147  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> alter table parts add column
       id int(11) not null auto_increment primary key first;
Query OK, 184147 rows affected (0.55 sec)
Records: 184147  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select id, code from parts limit 5;
+----+-------------------------+
| id | code                    |
+----+-------------------------+
|  1 | Yhk0KqSMeLcfH1KEfykihQ2 |
|  2 | IMl4iweZdmrBGvSUCtMCJA2 |
|  3 | rAKZUDj1WOnbkX_8S8mNbw2 |
|  4 | rV09rJ3X33-MPiNRcPTAwA2 |
|  5 | LPyIa_M_TOZ8655u1Ls5mA2 |
+----+-------------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So now I have the id column with correct data in `parts` table. After adding `part_id` column to `details` table:

```
mysql> alter table details add column part_id int(11) not null after part_code;
Query OK, 7278870 rows affected (1 min 17.74 sec)
Records: 7278870  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Now the big problem is how to update `part_id` accordingly? The following query:

```
mysql> update details d
       join parts p on d.part_code = p.code
       set d.part_id = p.id;
```

was running for about 30 hours until I killed it.

Note that both tables are MyISAM:

```
mysql> select engine from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'db_name' and (table_name = 'parts' or table_name = 'details');
+--------+
| ENGINE |
+--------+
| MyISAM |
| MyISAM |
+--------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I just now realized that one of the problems was that dropping the key on `parts` table I dropped the index on the `code` column. On the other side, I have the following indexes on `details` table (some irrelevant columns are omitted):

```
mysql> show indexes from details;
+---------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+------------+
| Table   | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Index_type |
+---------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+------------+
| details |          0 | PRIMARY  |            1 | sku         | A         |        NULL | BTREE      |
| details |          0 | PRIMARY  |            3 | part_code   | A         |     7278870 | BTREE      |
+---------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

### My questions are:

1. Is the update query OK or it can be optimized somehow?
2. I will add the index on the `code` column in `parts` table, will the query run in a reasonable time, or it will run for days again?
3. How can I make a (sql/bash/php) script so I can see the progress of the query execution?

Thank you very much!

Comment: The problem is with the partcode which is a varchar here, so the execution takes a lot of time\

Comment: I know the problem. That's why I'm trying to add the int column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I mentioned in the question, I forgot about the dropped indexes on the `parts` table, so I added them:

```
alter table parts add key code (code);
```

Inspired by Puggan Se's answer, I tried to use a `LIMIT` on `UPDATE` in a PHP script, but `LIMIT` can't be used with an `UPDATE` with `JOIN` in MySQL. To limit the query I added a new column to the `details` table:

```
# drop the primary key,
alter table details drop primary key;
# so I can create an auto_increment column
alter table details add id int not null auto_increment primary key;
# alter the id column and remove the auto_increment
alter table details change id id int not null;
# drop again the primary key
alter table details drop primary key;
# add new indexes
alter table details add primary key ( id, sku, num, part_code );
```

Now I can use the "limit":

```
update details d
join parts p on d.part_code = p.code
set d.part_id = p.id
where d.id between 1 and 5000;
```

So here's the full PHP script:

```
$started = time();
$i = 0;
$total = 7278870;

echo "Started at " . date('H:i:s', $started) . PHP_EOL;

function timef($s){
    $h = round($s / 3600);
    $h = str_pad($h, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $s = $s % 3600;
    $m = round( $s / 60);
    $m = str_pad($m, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    $s = $s % 60;
    $s = str_pad($s, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    return "$h:$m:$s";
}

while (1){
    $i++;
    $j = $i * 5000;
    $k = $j + 4999;
    $result = mysql_query("
        update details d
        join parts p on d.part_code = p.code
        set d.part_id = p.id
        where d.id between $j and $k
    ");
    if(!$result) die(mysql_error());
    if(mysql_affected_rows() == 0) die(PHP_EOL . 'Done!');
    $p = round(($i * 5000) / $total, 4) * 100;
    $s = time() - $started;
    $ela = timef($s);
    $eta = timef( (( $s / $p ) * 100) - $s );
    $eq = floor($p/10);
    $show_gt = ($p == 100);
    $spaces = $show_gt ? 9 - $eq : 10 - $eq;
    echo "\r {$p}% | [" . str_repeat('=', $eq) . ( $show_gt ? '' : '>' ) . str_repeat(' ', $spaces) . "] | Elapsed: ${ela} | ETA: ${eta}";
}
```

And here's a screenshot:

[image: working script screenshot]

As you can see, the whole thing took less than 5 minutes :)
Thank you all!

P.S.: There's still a bug because I found later 4999 rows left with `part_id = 0`, but I did that manually already.

Comment: like your terminal colors, remind me of old days when the monitor only got one color :-)

Answer (score 1):

1. You may want to add a where and a limit, so you can update it in chunks

   ```
   update details d
   join parts p on d.part_code = p.code
   set d.part_id = p.id
   WHERE d.part_id =0
   LIMIT 5000;
   ```
2. it will be alot faster whit index, and if you do one query as sugesten in '1' above, you can se how long 5000 rows takes to handle
3. loop above query

   ```
   while(TRUE)
   {
       $result = mysql_query($query);
       if(!$result) die('Failed: ' . mysql_error());
       if(mysql_affected_rows() == 0) die('Done');
       echo '.';
   }
   ```

**EDIT 1**
rewrite the query do to limit error on joins

You can use a subquery to avoid the multiple tables update:

```
UPDATE details
SET part_id = (SELECT id FROM parts WHERE parts.code = details.part_code)
WHERE part_id = 0
LIMIT 5000;
```

Comment: It fails. `LIMIT` cannot be used with `UPDATE`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/4291851/539153

Comment: Your answer inspired me. I solved by myself before seeing the edit. I will post now my solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove the indexes form the table you're trying to update. MySQL recreates the indexes on each row update. It won't be blazing fast for 7M records.

Comment: Mysql does not recreate the index for the columns that I don't update, but thank you for your answer