# Delete Row in a Table Based on a Lookup Value from Another Table

Tags: mysql

I have two (simplified) tables in a database.

```
Table: queuelist
'songID', 'lastplayed'
'7376', '12/01/2013'
'9322', '16/08/2012'

Table: songlist
'ID', 'artist'
'7376', 'Michael Jackson'
'2345', 'Nirvana'
```

`'songID'` and `'ID'` are the same fields.

I'm given `'Michael Jackson'` as an input and I want to delete the first row in `'queuelist'` based on looking up `'ID'` as the common field. I'm a MYSQL noob and have been trying examples but so far don't quite follow the syntax.

So far I have this...

```
DELETE S.songID
FROM queuelist Q,
(
JOIN songlist S
ON Q.songID = S.ID
)
WHERE S.artist = 'Michael Jackson'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `sub-query` in the `WHERE clause` rather than using `JOIN`.

```
DELETE FROM `queuelist`
WHERE       `songID` IN (SELECT `S`.`ID`
                         FROM   `songlist` `S`
                         WHERE  `S`.`artist` = 'Michael Jackson')
```

This will be the resulted data:

```
Table: queuelist
'songID', 'lastplayed'
'9322', '16/08/2012'

Table: songlist
'ID', 'artist'
'7376', 'Michael Jackson'
'2345', 'Nirvana'
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get an indent error (Syntax error, Unexpected IDENT_QUOTED, expecting END_OF_INPUT or ';') with that on the first Q. Any ideas?

Comment: @square_eyes Edited. Try now

Comment: Syntax error has gone but now I get Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'S.songID' in 'field list'

Comment: I think I found the issue. Should it be? ...

`DELETE FROM `queuelist`
WHERE       `songID` = (SELECT `S`.`ID`
                        FROM   `songlist` `S`
                        WHERE  `S`.`artist` = 'Michael Jackson')`

Comment: This produces the new error `Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Queries and reconnect.`

Comment: Which I don't really understand. Because there is a 'Where' clause. Do I have to disable safe mode?

Comment: I found a post that suggests using a limit constraint. Would this help?

Comment: @square_eyes Edited my query to the correct column name. Why isn't the songID column a key? Any way, you need to write `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;` on your DB. For further reading [MySQL error code: 1175 during UPDATE in MySQL Workbench](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench)

Comment: I'd rather not turn off Safe Updates if possible. To confuse matters queuelist has a column called 'ID' which is the key. It's not the same as songID or ID from the other table. I excluded it from the simplified example as I didn't think it would be used. FYI I have no control over the column names unfortunately.

Comment: @square_eyes Make `queueList`.`songId` a foreign key to `songList`.`id`

Comment: @square_eyes ley us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36462/discussion-between-itay-and-square-eyes)