# How to change root username in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, rename, root, superuser

I'm running MySQL in Ubuntu, default installation.

How can I change the username from `root` to another one, let's say `admin`? Preferably from the command line.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

After connecting to MySQL run

```
use mysql;
update user set user='admin' where user='root';
flush privileges;
```

That's it.

If you also want to change password, in MySQL < 5.7, run

```
update user set password=PASSWORD('new password') where user='admin';
```

before `flush privileges;`. In MySQL >= 5.7, the `password` field in the `user` table was renamed to `authentication_string`, so the above line becomes:

```
update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD('new password') where user='admin';
```

Comment: Will this affect the normal functioning of MySQL, which may require root user for something? Or is it safe to change that username for MySQL hardening?

Comment: It shouldn't affect normal functioning of MySQL.

Comment: Just wondering, if there is any option or workaround to set a user name alias, being able to use both names `root` and `admin` for the same root account.

Comment: if use mysql workbench, you need to deactivate the safe update mode: Edit -> Preferences -> Sql Editor then uncheck Safe update. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench

Comment: table user doesnt exists

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to say that for me, there was no column 'password'.

To change password, the correct field was authentication_string

So the command is

```
update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD('new password') where user='admin';
```

I'm no MySQL expert, so I'm not sure exactly why, but what I said is correct, at least in my case.

Comment: This happens only after MySQL 5.7, it was not the case when I posted my answer. I updated my answer.

Comment: Changed again in [MySQL-8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) best refer back to the manual if you ever need to do this.

Answer (score -1):

For example, you can change the username `root` to `john` as shown below. *I recommend to use `RENAME USER ...` because directly modifying `mysql.user` is sometimes problematic. *You probably need to log in with the user `root`:

```sql
RENAME USER 'root'@'localhost' to 'john'@'localhost';
```

Or:

```sql
UPDATE mysql.user SET User='john' WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then, you can log in to MySQL:

```
mysql -u john -p
```