# Username 'root' can be changed in mysql or i can suppose there always be a user named 'root' having all privileges?

Tags: mysql, root, privileges

Question explain itself. In mysql i can *always* suppose there will be a user named 'root' having all privileges or the name can be changed?
I'm writing a shell script that needs to do some administrative task on a database and i was guessing if i have to ask user only root password or root username too.

Comment: Not always. It can be changed. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539028/how-can-i-change-root-username-in-mysql

Comment: Even if they don't change the root username it's still possible to make the root user locked down to just localhost or make it not have a working password(change the password hash to `*!` is the typical solution). Never trust the root user to work.

Comment: What do you mean by "change the password hash"? I guess i don't understand what you mean in this case for "hash"

Comment: MySQL stores a hash of your login users passwords, this means that when you log in it hashes your attempted password and compares the hash results. If your database is ever compromised no-one can see the actual passwords of it's users, only their hashes. By making the value of the hash MySQL stores one that is impossible to return(By claiming it's a 33byte value with the leading asterisk, then putting less than 33 bytes in as the value for example) you ensure that there is no way to log in as the intended user.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can(After logging into mysql)  :

```
use mysql;
update user set user='urDesiredName' where user='root';
```

`Mysql` is a database that contains user regarding information like names, roles, priviledges  etc informations.

do `flush privileges;`  It will only clear the db cache and will reset root to [userNewRoot].

Comment: Exactly what i was searching for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this

```
use mysql;
update user set user='admin' where user='root';
flush privileges;
```