# MySQL delete table with regard to referential integrity rules

Tags: mysql, database, integrity, referential

I want to delete `tableA` while removing all rows in `tableB` that have matching `tableA.A_ID = tableB.A_ID`

Currently I have a foreign key set to `CASCADE` on delete and update set on `TableB` for `tableB.A_ID`.

Comment: depending on which direction you are going. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/2917374/1816093

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn constraints temporarily off by

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;

DELETE FROM tableB b WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM tableA a WHERE a.A_ID = b.A_ID )

DELETE FROM tableA;

SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
```

Comment: So turn off checks then delete the rows in tableB then delete tableA?

Comment: @RiCHiE, I thought it was about the constraints only. See update, **please backup your tables before you try it out**!

Comment: Hmm I'm still getting an error in MySQL workbench "You are using safe mode" although i disabled safe mode in options as well. Do I need to execute in shell?

Comment: @RiCHiE, see update, honestly cant say if it works - found it here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841353/mysql-delete-under-safe-mode ...must admit I have never experienced that error message myself.