# MariaDB, Delete with condition not working

Tags: mariadb, conditional-statements, sql-delete

I'm building an App and using MariaDB as my database.
I have a table "kick_votes". Its primary key consits of three fields:

- user_id
- group_id
- vote_id

I need to delete rows where user_id AND group_id fulfill my conditions or just the vote_id.
I enabled the config, that I have to use a key column in my WHERE clause for security issues.

This one is working correctly:

```
 DELETE FROM kick_votes WHERE (user_id=86 AND group_id=10);
 DELETE FROM kick_votes WHERE vote_id=2;
```

But I don't want to use two statements, but the following doesn't work:

```
DELETE FROM kick_votes WHERE (user_id=86 AND group_id=10) OR vote_id=2;
```

I get the error:

> You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a 
>        WHERE that uses a KEY column.

Why isn't it working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL error code: 1175 during UPDATE in MySQL Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench)

Comment: Can you show us the actual table/primary key definition?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysql delete under safe mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841353/mysql-delete-under-safe-mode)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like key existence doesn't actually affect the error.
From mariadb sources, `mysql_delete`:

```
const_cond= (!conds || conds->const_item());
safe_update= MY_TEST(thd->variables.option_bits & OPTION_SAFE_UPDATES);
if (safe_update && const_cond)
{
  my_message(ER_UPDATE_WITHOUT_KEY_IN_SAFE_MODE,
             ER_THD(thd, ER_UPDATE_WITHOUT_KEY_IN_SAFE_MODE), MYF(0));
  DBUG_RETURN(TRUE);
}
```

So the only variant is to turn off safe mode:

```
set @@sql_safe_updates= 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Kludge:

```
DELETE FROM kick_votes
    WHERE id > 0    -- assuming this is your PRIMARY KEY
      AND (    (user_id=86 AND group_id=10)
            OR vote_id=2
          );
```