# MySQL You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have been getting this error message from mySQL

> "Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to
>   update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe
>   mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect. "

The query I use is this:

```
 UPDATE table1 a INNER JOIN table2 asa ON a.ID = asa.Table1Id SET a.ReferenceID = asa.ReferenceID WHERE a.ID > 0 AND asa.ID > 0
```

I do have where clauses for both tables on IDs which are Primary key for both tables.

Disabling the SQL_SAFE_UPDATES is not an option.

Edit: MySQL version is v5.6

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841353/mysql-delete-under-safe-mode  Look at Peter B's answer

Comment: No that is not an option for me

Comment: It looks like you just want to do all ID's correct?  And the > isn't working becuase I believe MySQL knows that.  But you can't use the <> 0 trick?  Do you have negative id's you are trying to protect?

Comment: [I can't reproduce](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qkA6BvQxLrCwMseSRm3JfX/0)

Comment: @bjk116 If I use '<>' or '!=' I get the same issue

Comment: @Cid I can reproduce it in your link also. Forgot to mention that I use v5.6

Comment: Ok yea just confirmed things on my 5.6 system.  An admittedly hacky non-nice work around is to select all the appropriate id you do want to update in a select query.  Copy and past this to NotePad++ or something similar, then you can format it into a (id1, id2,....idn) format.  Then change your update query to WHERE t.id IN (id1, id2, ...idn).

Not ideal and definitely not what you want to do every time but if you're in a rush/need this now, it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that MySQL 5.6 is limited about executing an `UPDATE` statement along with a `JOIN`

So, instead of

```
UPDATE table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 asa
ON a.ID = asa.Table1Id
SET a.ReferenceID = asa.ReferenceID
WHERE a.ID > 0 AND asa.ID > 0
```

You'll have to write as many queries as needed like :

```
UPDATE table1 a
SET a.ReferenceID = <The corresponding value in table 2>
WHERE a.ID = <The corresponding ID>
```

This being pretty annoying to type, one can use dynamic SQL to build the update queries :

```
SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE table1 a SET a.ReferenceID = ', asa.ReferenceID, ' WHERE a.ID = ', t.ID, ';')
FROM table1 t
INNER JOIN table2 asa
ON t.ID = asa.Table1Id;
```

In example :

**Schema (MySQL v5.6)**

```
CREATE TABLE test
(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    foo VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE test2
(
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    id_test INT NOT NULL,
    foo VARCHAR(255),
    FOREIGN KEY (id_test) REFERENCES test(id)
);

INSERT INTO test (foo) VALUES ('hello'), ('world');

INSERT INTO test2 (id_test, foo) VALUES (1, 'bar'), (2, 'baz');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT CONCAT('UPDATE test t SET t.foo = ''', t2.foo, ''' WHERE t.id = ', t.id, ';') AS 'sql query'
FROM test t
INNER JOIN test2 t2
ON t.id = t2.id_test;
```

This outputs :

```
UPDATE test t SET t.foo = 'bar' WHERE t.id = 1;
UPDATE test t SET t.foo = 'baz' WHERE t.id = 2;
```

The output can now be used to *manually* update the differents rows

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qkA6BvQxLrCwMseSRm3JfX/2)

Comment: It works, problem is that I have more than 1 million entries in the tables. And because of that I would not want to do it like this.

Comment: Can you write a python script?  Sucks, but I'm not sure how many other options you have.  You're trying to update all rows at once with a setting that prevents all rows at once from being updated.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you are using the `KEYS`,I guess the `KEYS` are **not properly used**. [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sql_safe_updates) says.

> If this variable is enabled, UPDATE and DELETE statements that do not use a key in the WHERE clause or a LIMIT clause produce an error. This makes it possible to catch UPDATE and DELETE statements where keys are **not used properly** and that would probably change or delete a large number of rows.

Your query below will affect same number of rows even with `WHERE` conditions. I suppose all the values of `ID` is more than `0` right? If so,then that is the reason for your error.

```
 UPDATE table1 a 
 INNER JOIN table2 asa 
 ON a.ID = asa.Table1Id 
 SET a.ReferenceID = asa.ReferenceID 
 --WHERE a.ID > 0 AND asa.ID > 0
```

One way is as suggested  `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;` (disable and try). Or try refining the `WHERE` condition. Also you can use `LIMIT` if it is a single table.