# How can I got clear the error while running UPDATE query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL WORKBENCH 6.1.6. I need to update my database_table. I have tried the following coding:

```
UPDATE `test`.`festexplorer_users`
SET
User_preference = 'All_Over_India' 
WHERE User_year_of_passing=2015;
```

Here, "test" is my database name, festexplorer_users is my table name and I need to update the column User_preference. I have got the following error.

```
Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a                  
WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL 
Queries    and reconnect.
```

How could I clear my error?

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench

Comment: Oh... I got it... Thanks for your response

Comment: you need to check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench

Comment: @MukulBhardwaj I got cleared all the doubts about that error.... Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your MySQL WorkBench go to

- Edit -> Preferences -> SQL Queries

  Uncheck Forbid UPDATE and DELETE
  statements without a WHERE clause (safe updates)

then

- Query --> Reconnect     to Server