# Update query not working in mysql workbench

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I have a MySql query, which is given below:

```
UPDATE signup SET lastname='Lastname', password='123'
WHERE firstname='Firstname';
```

I am using MySql Workbench to execute the query.

But it's not updating the row and shows this error:

> You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without
>   a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option
>   in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

Comment: "showing error" => which one ?

Comment: my error is - You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

Comment: please have a look on similar questionhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In mysql workbench the safe mode is enabled by default, so if your `WHERE` clause doesn't have a key it will prevent running the query. Try disabling that using these steps -

`Edit` > `Preferences` > `Sql Editor` > `uncheck the "Safe Updates"`

**Note** - try reconnecting the server (`Query` > `Reconnect to Server`) and than run your query again.

Comment: To apply this solution please do restart your MySQL workbench after unchecking it and it will work.

Answer (score 10):

`MySQL` helps you particularly avoid updating/deleting multiple rows in one shot. To achieve that, it doesn't allow you to run `UPDATE` queries without passing the ID parameter. This is called as the `SAFE UPDATES` mode.

As said by @ManojSalvi, you can set it permanently from the settings.

In case you want to temporarily disable the `SAFE UPDATE` mode, you can try the following:-

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
UPDATE signup SET lastname='Lastname', password='123'
WHERE firstname='Firstname';
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

[edit]
@ManojSalvi got it, workbench related

[MySQL error code: 1175 during UPDATE in MySQL Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench)

---

Work fine for me...

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d41ae/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t
    (`firstname` varchar(6), `lastname` varchar(14), `password` varchar(3))
;

INSERT INTO t
    (`firstname`, `lastname`, `password`)
VALUES
    ('Pramod', 'Alfred', '***'),
    ('test', 'hello h.', '***')
;
UPDATE t SET lastname='Alfred Schmidt', password='123' WHERE firstname='Pramod';
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * from t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d41ae/1/0)**:

```
| firstname |       lastname | password |
|-----------|----------------|----------|
|    Pramod | Alfred Schmidt |      123 |
|      test |       hello h. |      *** |
```

Comment: as he already explained it is not working in the workbench, it has nothing to do with the query itself

Comment: @davejal He only give us the error message **after** my post, so I was not able to find it was workbench related, after that I've make [a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33971357/update-query-not-work-in-mysql-workbench/33971406?noredirect=1#comment55699401_33971357) with a link to [error code: 1175 during UPDATE in MySQL Workbench](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench)

Comment: ok, I removed the downvote, but still your answer isn't helpfull stating it works fine for you. You should try to find out why it isn't working for him

Comment: @davejal thx; reproducing a bug is the first thing to do : showing the same code working may help to find a mistyping or an environment related bug (like this one, as it's the safemode of workbench in fault and not mysql); but yes, I usually try to be more helpful ;)

Answer (score 1):

"Safe mode" is on by default in MySQL workbench. You can change it go to mysqlworkbench at the top left –> preferences–> sql editor –> uncheck the safe mode and then try reconnecting. Or you can just type

**SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;**

This will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has anything to to with the `SAFE UPDATES` since you have clearly stated `WHERE` you wanted to make changes.
I had the same issue, but I tried wrapping the *column's name* in backticks ` and it worked. You can find backticks to the left of number 1 on the keyboard.

One other thing you can try is to `SELECT` the *table* and double click on the item you want to `UPDATE` then apply the changes at the bottom right of the window.