# Add a prefix to all values of a column in a MYSQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database table where I need to add the prefix "35-" to all values of a certain column/field (`productcode`) whose `category` number is higher tahn 500. So I would for example want productcode value `123A56B789` be changed to `35-123A56B789`, and similar in all other rows of the table.

An additional problem is that this column is the primary key of that table, but I tried to work around that by adding an additional index column, defining that as the primary key, erasing the index on "productcode" and trying the following query (with the intention to later define it as a primary index again):

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET productcode = '35-' + productcode
WHERE category >= 500
```

I get no error or warning messages (even a message "xxxx rows affected"), but there is no visible effect whatsoever - the productcodes stay the same as they were before.

Is there a method to achieve this directly in MYSQL?

Comment: Its a long shot but try to add a where clause. `WHERE 1 = 1` or something like that.

Comment: Also, did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/33971431/3179169?

Comment: @clinomaniac Actually, I do have a WHERE clause in my query, I added it now to the question. But I don't really know what you are referring to in your comments...

Comment: I was just going after the `safe updates` check. But since you have the where clause, it doesn't apply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `CONCAT` to add 35- to the start of your productcode column. Check it.

```
UPDATE my_table SET productcode = CONCAT('35-', productcode) WHERE category >= 500;
```

Comment: perfect, that's exactly what I was looking for - thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome. If it worked, please accept the answer. Thanks.