# Updation not done in procedure after inserting a record in same table

Tags: mysql, cursor

I inserted record into a table with the help of Cursor and loop  after closing cursor i wrote update statement to update some record which inserted by cursor so reords not updating. but i ran query outside then records updating

my try is
drop procedure if exists kpsf_inopdormantac;

```
create procedure kpsf_inopdormantac(inp_branchcode varchar(6), inp_date date)

begin  declare c_branchcode varchar(6);
declare c_accounttype varchar(4); 
declare c_accountsubtype varchar(6); 
declare c_accountno varchar(12);
declare c_lasttxndate date;
declare c_inopdate date;
declare c_temp varchar(25);

declare c1 cursor for SELECT
branchcode, accounttype, accountsubtype, accountno, lasttxndate, inoperativedate FROM accountmaster WHERE branchcode = inp_branchcode AND accounttype in ('10','11') AND accountstatus!='C' AND lasttxndate < ( SELECT date_add(inp_date,interval -24 month));

truncate table inopdormantac;
commit;
open c1;
loop1:loop fetch c1 into c_branchcode, c_accounttype, c_accountsubtype, c_accountno, c_lasttxndate, c_inopdate;

INSERT into inopdormantac (branchcode, accounttype, accountsubtype, accountno, acstatus, lasttxndate, inopdate)
VALUES 
(c_branchcode, c_accounttype, c_accountsubtype, c_accountno, 'InOperative', c_lasttxndate, c_inopdate);

end loop loop1;
close c1;
set c_temp='InActive';

update inopdormantac SET acstatus = c_temp WHERE lasttxndate < ( SELECT
date_add('2015-10-06',interval -120 month));
end;
```

plz help me

Answer (score 0):

Potentially you might be running DB instance in safe-updates mode. Please see another question which have been already answered:
[MySQL error code: 1175 during UPDATE in MySQL Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench)

Comment: i done SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;

alter table inopdormantac add primary key (accountid,lasttxndate)

Comment: i added one more column in table accountid then added primary key and tried but not working