# How to avoid MySQL Workbench error code: 1175 during this UPDATE *without* disabling "safe updates"

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a particular MySQL `UPDATE` statement which *does* specify the required primary key in its `WHERE` clause and yet which still produces Error 1175 when run in MySQL Workbench.

I am perfectly aware of [MySQL error code: 1175 during UPDATE in MySQL Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench).  My case appears to be the same as [MySQL error code: 1175 during UPDATE (MySQL-Workbench vs. console)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41687196/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-mysql-workbench-vs-console). Like that questioner, I do *not* wish to disable MySQL-Workbench's "safe update/delete" option.  That question failed to get a solution.  I would like to try to get an actual solution.

SQL `UPDATE` statement:

`` -- update new columns' values from corresponding rows in `charges_arc`
UPDATE `charges`
INNER JOIN `charges_arc` ON `charges`.`ChargeID` = `charges_arc`.`ChargeID`
    SET `charges`.`ChargeClearDate` = `charges_arc`.`ChargeClearDate`
      WHERE `charges`.`ChargeID` = `charges_arc`.`ChargeID`; ``

`ChargeID` is indeed the Primary Key column in both `charges` and `charges_arc` tables.

This means that this statement *does* satisfy MySQL Workbench's https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/workbench-faq.html#faq-workbench-delete-safe:

> By default, Workbench is configured to not execute DELETE or UPDATE
>   queries that do not include a WHERE clause on a KEY column.

Is there a solution to rewrite this query such that Workbench does not Error 1175, and which does *not* require setting `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0`/changing Workbench's preferences?

Comment: Interesting.  Perhaps the issue is that the join in your update widens the number of records which could be deleted, i.e. just specifying a primary key is not "safe" anymore because it could still in theory include a large chunk of the table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That in turn is an interesting theory.  I was thinking of trying rewriting it to not use `JOIN` but instead change to sub-query `WHERE charges.ChargeID IN ( SELECT charges_arc.ChargeID FROM charges_arc WHERE charges_arc.ChargeID = charges.ChargeID )`, but if your theory is correct it might fall foul there too.  Since I've typed this in, I'll give it a go now...

Comment: Whoops, you can't access `charges_arc`.`ChargeClearDate` in the `SET` clause if you use the sub-query idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, having played further, so far I have found that the following seems to keep Workbench happy:

`` -- update new columns' values from corresponding rows in `charges_arc`
UPDATE `charges`
INNER JOIN `charges_arc` ON `charges`.`ChargeID` = `charges_arc`.`ChargeID`
    SET `charges`.`ChargeClearDate` = `charges_arc`.`ChargeClearDate`
      WHERE `charges`.`ChargeID` = `charges_arc`.`ChargeID`
      AND `charges`.`ChargeID` <> -9999 ``

That's just adding `AND charges.ChargeID <> -9999` to the condition.  It hardly narrows the scope much(!), and it's pretty ugly(!).  I can only guess that Workbench would like to "see some kind of *literal* test against the PK", so that you show it you have thought about the PK in a certain way!  It does at least allow you to do the query without disabling "safe updates".

I will leave this open for a couple of days to see if someone can think of something neater.

For my own part, I have a lot of these kind of `UPDATE`s in a large upgrading script file, this looks so ugly to me that I may end up going for `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0` over the whole file after all...

**EDIT**: In the end I decided it was so ugly having to add something like the extra `AND` clause above to these types of `UPDATE ... JOIN ...`s that I preferred to `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0` around them, at least for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Using MySQL 5.6 and MySQLWorkbench 8, I received this error in the same circumstances. I was able to fix the error by qualifying the field name in the WHERE clause.

For example, this caused the 1175 error:

```
UPDATE `tReports`
SET
`Title` = Title,
`Descr` = Descr
WHERE `ID` = ID;
```

And this resolved it:

```
UPDATE `tReports`
SET
`Title` = Title,
`Descr` = Descr
WHERE `tReports`.`ID` = ID;
```