# safe mode sql php issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an issue with php/mysql. When I want to update or delete an entry in a table with php, I have this error :

> Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to
>   update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe
>   mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Queries and reconnect.

I tried to set MYSQL_SAFE_UPDATES to 0 but it still doesn't work.

I also read this post : [MySQL error code: 1175 during UPDATE in MySQL Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench) and it didn't solve my problem

Does anyone have a tip ?

code:

```
$sql2 = "update $table set ";
           $sql3 = "insert into $table"."_ (";
           $find;
           foreach ($arr2 as $name) {
                if($name != "user"){
                    $id2 ='inp'.$k;
                    if(isset($_POST[$id2])){ 
                        $val = $_POST[$id2];
                        $sql3.= $name.",";
                    }
                    $k++;
                }
                else{
                    $find = $k;
                    //$k++;
                }
           }
           $sql3 = substr($sql3,0,-1);
           $sql3.=") ";
           $sql3.= " values( ";
           $check = "select * from $table where ";
           $k=0;
           $f=0;
           foreach ($arr as $name) {
                    if($arr2[$k] != "user"){
                        $id2 ='inp'.$f;
                        if(isset($_POST[$id2])){
                            $val = $_POST[$id2];
                           // echo $val."  ";
                            if(isset($_POST[$id2])){
                                if ((strpos($name, 'int') !== false || strpos($name,'float') !== false) && (!empty($val) && is_numeric ($val))){
                                    $sql2.= $arr2[$k]."=".$val.", ";
                                    $check.= $arr2[$k]."=".$val." and ";
                                    $sql3.= $val.",";
                                }
                                else{
                                    if(strpos($name, 'varchar') !== false){
                                        $sql2.= $arr2[$k]."='".$val."', ";
                                        $check.= $arr2[$k]."='".$val."' and ";
                                        $sql3.= "'".$val."',";
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        if ((strpos($name, 'int') !== false || strpos($name,'float') !== false) && (!empty($val) && !is_numeric ($val))){
                                           goto error;
                                           break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            else{
                               $sql2.=$arr2[$k]."="."NULL,";
                               $check.=$arr2[$k]."="."NULL and ";
                               $sql3.="NULL,";
                            }
                            $f++;
                        }
                    }
                    $k++;
           }
           $use = $_SESSION['user'];
           $check = substr($check,0,-5);
           $check.=";";
           $sth = $conn->prepare("$check");
           $sth->execute();
           $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
           if(!$row){
               $sql2 = substr($sql2, 0, -2);
               $sql2.=" where ";
               $i = 0;
               $j=0;
               $bool = 0;
               if(isset($_SESSION['tab'])){
                   foreach ($arr as $name) {
                       if($arr2[$i] != "user"){
                           $id2 ='inp'.$j;
                           if(isset($_POST[$id2])){
                              $val = $_SESSION['tab'][$j];
                              if($id2 != ""){
                                   $sql2.= $arr2[$i]."=";
                                   if ((strpos($name, 'int') !== false || strpos($name,'float') !== false) && (!empty($val) && is_numeric ($val))){
                                       $sql2.= $val." and ";
                                   }
                                   else{
                                        if(strpos($name,'varchar') !== false){
                                            $sql2.= "'".$val."' and ";
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            if(empty($val)){
                                                $sql2.= $arr2[$i]." IS NULL and ";
                                            }
                                            else{
                                                if ((strpos($name, 'int') !== false || strpos($name,'float') !== false) && (!empty($val) && !is_numeric ($val))){
                                                    goto error;
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                   }
                              }
                              unset($_POST[$id2]);
                              $j++;
                          }
                          else{
                               $sql2.= $arr2[$i]." IS NULL and ";
                          }
                        }
                      $i++;
                   }
                   unset($_SESSION['tab']);
               }
               else{
                    echo "ici";
                   goto error;
                   $bool = -1;
               }
               if($bool != -1){
                   $sql2 = substr($sql2,0,-5);
                   $sql2.=";";
                   try{
                       $sth = $conn->prepare("$sql2");
                       $sth->execute();
                   }
                   catch(Exception $e){
                        echo $e;
                   }
                   $sql3 = substr($sql3,0,-1);
                   $sql3.=");";
                   try{
                       $sth = $conn->prepare("$sql3");
                       $sth->execute();
                   }
                   catch(Exception $e){
                        echo $e;
                   }
                   echo $sql2."<br/>".$sql3."<br/>";
                   unset($_POST['sub']);
                   //redirect('database.php', 303);
              }
            }
            else{
                echo $check;
                goto error;
            }
        }
        error : 
            if(isset($e))
                echo $e;
```

this is the echo statement:

update recherche set date='erzerze', coordonnees='zeraezr', typeMilieu='Forêt', responsable='azerazer', observateurPreleveur='azerazer', projet='azerazer', observations='Flore', prelevements='Flore', experimentations='Identification', commentaires=' ', test='rtrt' where date='erzerze' and coordonnees='zeraezr' and typeMilieu='Forêt' and responsable='azerazer' and observateurPreleveur='azerazer' and projet='azerazer' and observations='Flore' and prelevements='Flore' and experimentations='Identification' and commentaires=' ' and test='';

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL error code: 1175 during UPDATE in MySQL Workbench](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench)

Comment: I have already seen this post, that's why I'm here because this answer didn't help me to get out of this issue

Comment: It could also be one of the other answers on that page, for example the original poster fixed his issue by prepending the schema to his query so `databasename.tablename`

Comment: Can you please post the actual code that sets the safe update variable and does the update?

Comment: I'm posting it, but it's a large part of code because I have to use multiple array

Comment: Could you echo the statements and show those?

Comment: great code you have there :) just add yourself an reminder to see it again in 2 or 3 years :)

Comment: I have posted the echo value