# Mysql Update Issue with SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;

Tags: mysql

I am having Serious Issue with my Mysql 5.7.6 .When I try to update my simple table .Can any one find my issue for update below table . When I got SQL_SAFE_UPDATES  related problem then I have follow all step of [STACK_OVERFLOW_LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench)  but here issue is some thing different

We can have loop on log also 
The line wants to tell different

```
 11:10:19   UPDATE `mydb`.`dailyreport` SET `outTime`="19:42:51" WHERE `idDailyReport`='50468'  0 row(s) affected
     Rows matched: 1  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0   0.375 sec
```

**Why my outTime field is not updateing ??**
[image: WorkBench_View]

Comment: I have tryed using command line Client but same Respose log

Comment: try by restarting the server or reconnecting to it,  because no problem seems in your query

Comment: for reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench

Comment: do your problem get solved @SurajKhanra

Answer (score -1):

IT has SHOWN that Rows matched: 1 AND  Changed: 0 Because you are updating the same value twice i.e. you are not changing the value of the row hence it is showing 
Changed: 0

try to update again with different values

Comment: can you please if my update successfully run and then I select that rows what should be the result set value ???