# MySql safe mode delete

Tags: mysql

I am using MySql 5.7

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `session`;
CREATE TABLE `session` (
`Id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`Browser` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`IpAddress` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`UserId` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
`CreatedAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`ModifiedAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`CreatedBy` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
`ModifiedBy` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
);


DELETE FROM session 
WHERE Id IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT Id FROM session WHERE CreatedAt > NOW()) AS temp);
```

I am getting an error: Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.  0.000 sec

I dont think disabling safe update is a good idea. Turn off save mode [answers  here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench)
Maybe there is other solution. Any ideas ?

Added dummy condition !=''  and delete works

```
DELETE FROM session 
WHERE Id !='' AND Id IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT Id FROM session WHERE Browser = "Mozilla") AS temp);
```

select * from session;

Dummy conditions like Id IS NOT NULL  or Id IN ("some_dummy_id_here") doesnt works

Thanks to @tim-biegeleisen  for help !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps you could try adding a dummy condition to the `WHERE` clause which uses the key, e.g.

```
DELETE FROM session 
WHERE Id <> '' AND
      Id IN (SELECT * FROM (SELECT Id FROM session WHERE CreatedAt > NOW()) AS temp);
```

Assuming that the primary key column `Id` is always not empty string, then adding this condition won't affect your delete logic.

As you mentioned, you could also disable safe mode in your session via:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
```

If you are paranoid/cautious, you could even turn safe updates back on after executing your delete query:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
```

Comment: Id is PK.  I tried "is not null"  and "Id IN ("dummy_Id_here")" doesnt work

Comment: Please post the table structure for `session`.

Comment: updated question with table. We use GUID for Id , that is why it is varchar(128)

Comment: I'm surprised my answer didn't work.  If you read the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench), you will see a few answers suggesting the trick which I suggested above.

Comment: You think its ok to have SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0; than delete query and SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1 ?