# how to delete records less than 2 days for each id based on time field

Tags: mysql

**Input**

```
id  lst_redeem_op_time
a  2020-07-22 11:14:37
a  2020-07-28 11:14:37
a  2020-07-30 14:55:04
b  2020-07-27 11:14:37
b  2020-07-28 11:14:37
b  2020-08-15 11:14:37
c  2020-07-27 11:14:37
c  2020-07-29 11:14:37
c  2020-07-31 11:14:37
```

**Expected**

```
id  lst_redeem_op_time
a  2020-07-22 11:14:37
a  2020-07-30 14:55:04
b  2020-07-27 11:14:37
b  2020-07-28 11:14:37
b  2020-08-15 11:14:37
c  2020-07-27 11:14:37
c  2020-07-31 11:14:37
```

For each `id`, delete records where the datediff between the date of `lst_redeem_op_time` and the date of latest time less than 2 days. The latest time is not '2020-08-15 11:14:37' but it's the max time for each id. `(a:2020-07-30 14:55:04, b:2020-08-15 11:14:37, c:2020-07-31 11:14:37)`

**Try**

I search these [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47269595/delete-rows-older-than-14-days-in-mysql), [post2](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59238/mysql-keep-the-10-most-recent-rows-for-each-user) but still cannot get it.

**version**

- 5.5

Comment: I have no idea how you get to your expected result. Why for example does a  2020-07-28 11:14:37 drop out?

Comment: @P.Salmon using mysql datediff is 2 days , the record you gave should be dropped.

Comment: I'm also struggling to see the logic for retaining c27 and excluding a28

Comment: *delete records where the datediff between lst_redeem_op_time and **latest time** less than 2 days.* Why (b, 2020-07-27 11:14:37) was deleted? Latest time for it is 2020-08-15 11:14:37... Maybe you need not "latest" but "next"?

Comment: @P.Salmon@Strawberry@Akina I update my question. Is it clear?

Comment: `'2020-07-30 14:55:04' - INTERVAL 48 HOUR = '2020-07-28 14:55:04'`

Comment: @Strawberry I update it, using mysql datediff is 2 days.

Comment: What's the logic for removing b27 from the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With reference to the amended result set, I *think* you're after something like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,lst_redeem_op_time DATETIME NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY (id,lst_redeem_op_time)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('a','2020-07-22 11:14:37'),
('a','2020-07-28 11:14:37'),
('a','2020-07-30 14:55:04'),
('b','2020-07-27 11:14:37'),
('b','2020-07-28 11:14:37'),
('b','2020-08-15 11:14:37'),
('c','2020-07-27 11:14:37'),
('c','2020-07-29 11:14:37'),
('c','2020-07-31 11:14:37');

SELECT a.*  
  FROM my_table a
  LEFT
  JOIN
     ( SELECT id, MAX(lst_redeem_op_time) lst_redeem_op_time FROM my_table GROUP BY id) b
    ON b.id = a.id
   AND b.lst_redeem_op_time > a.lst_redeem_op_time
   AND DATEDIFF(b.lst_redeem_op_time,a.lst_redeem_op_time) <= 2
 WHERE b.id IS NULL;
+----+---------------------+
| id | lst_redeem_op_time  |
+----+---------------------+
| a  | 2020-07-22 11:14:37 |
| a  | 2020-07-30 14:55:04 |
| b  | 2020-07-27 11:14:37 |
| b  | 2020-07-28 11:14:37 |
| b  | 2020-08-15 11:14:37 |
| c  | 2020-07-27 11:14:37 |
| c  | 2020-07-31 11:14:37 |
+----+---------------------+
```

A DELETE for this might be as follows, but I would question the wisdom of deleting data from your database...

```
DELETE a.* -- .* is meaningless in this context, but MySQL allows it anyway
  FROM my_table a
  JOIN
     ( SELECT id, MAX(lst_redeem_op_time) lst_redeem_op_time FROM my_table GROUP BY id) b
    ON b.id = a.id
   AND b.lst_redeem_op_time > a.lst_redeem_op_time
   AND DATEDIFF(b.lst_redeem_op_time,a.lst_redeem_op_time) <= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the DELETE with INNER JOIN
Akina pointed out that the date calculation should be made in the subquery

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `id` VARCHAR(1),
>   `lst_redeem_op_time` DATETIME
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`id`, `lst_redeem_op_time`)
> VALUES
>   ('a', '2020-07-22 11:14:37'),
>   ('a', '2020-07-28 11:14:37'),
>   ('a', '2020-07-30 14:55:04'),
>   ('b', '2020-07-27 11:14:37'),
>   ('b', '2020-07-28 11:14:37'),
>   ('b', '2020-08-15 11:14:37'),
>   ('c', '2020-07-27 11:14:37'),
>   ('c', '2020-07-29 11:14:37'),
>   ('c', '2020-07-31 11:14:37');
> ```

> ```
>  SELECT 
>  t1.`id`, `lst_redeem_op_time`
>  FROM table1 t1 
>  INNER JOIN       (SELECT `id`, MAX(DATE_ADD(`lst_redeem_op_time`, INTERVAL - 2 DAY)) max_time FROM table1 GROUP BY id) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
> WHERE t1.`lst_redeem_op_time` < t2.max_time;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | lst_redeem_op_time 
> :- | :------------------
> a  | 2020-07-22 11:14:37
> a  | 2020-07-28 11:14:37
> b  | 2020-07-27 11:14:37
> b  | 2020-07-28 11:14:37
> c  | 2020-07-27 11:14:37
> ```

> ```
> DELETE t1
> FROM table1 t1
>         INNER JOIN
>       (SELECT `id`, MAX(DATE_ADD(`lst_redeem_op_time`, INTERVAL - 2 DAY)) max_time FROM table1 GROUP BY id) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
> WHERE t1.`lst_redeem_op_time` < t2.max_time;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table1
> ```
>
> ```
> id | lst_redeem_op_time 
> :- | :------------------
> a  | 2020-07-30 14:55:04
> b  | 2020-08-15 11:14:37
> c  | 2020-07-29 11:14:37
> c  | 2020-07-31 11:14:37
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4d37c920de5f27921898827b928a72cc)*

even using DATEDIFF

The result is never the wanted result

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `id` VARCHAR(1),
>   `lst_redeem_op_time` DATETIME
> );
>
> INSERT INTO table1
>   (`id`, `lst_redeem_op_time`)
> VALUES
>   ('a', '2020-07-22 11:14:37'),
>   ('a', '2020-07-28 11:14:37'),
>   ('a', '2020-07-30 14:55:04'),
>   ('b', '2020-07-27 11:14:37'),
>   ('b', '2020-07-28 11:14:37'),
>   ('b', '2020-08-15 11:14:37'),
>   ('c', '2020-07-27 11:14:37'),
>   ('c', '2020-07-29 11:14:37'),
>   ('c', '2020-07-31 11:14:37');
> ```

> ```
>  SELECT 
>  t1.`id`, `lst_redeem_op_time`
>  FROM table1 t1 
>  INNER JOIN       (SELECT `id`, MAX(`lst_redeem_op_time`) max_time FROM table1 GROUP BY id) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
> WHERE DATEDIFF(t2.max_time,t1.`lst_redeem_op_time`)   > 2 ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | lst_redeem_op_time 
> :- | :------------------
> a  | 2020-07-22 11:14:37
> b  | 2020-07-27 11:14:37
> b  | 2020-07-28 11:14:37
> c  | 2020-07-27 11:14:37
> ```

> ```
> DELETE t1
> FROM table1 t1
>  INNER JOIN       (SELECT `id`, MAX(`lst_redeem_op_time`) max_time FROM table1 GROUP BY id) t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
> WHERE DATEDIFF(t2.max_time,t1.`lst_redeem_op_time`)   > 2 ;
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM table1
> ```
>
> ```
> id | lst_redeem_op_time 
> :- | :------------------
> a  | 2020-07-28 11:14:37
> a  | 2020-07-30 14:55:04
> b  | 2020-08-15 11:14:37
> c  | 2020-07-29 11:14:37
> c  | 2020-07-31 11:14:37
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b690150f9e831d1352bf4704f639056f)*

Comment: Shouldn't the results align with the question?

Comment: Perform DATEADD in the subquery - this will decrease the calculations amount...

Comment: You are both right, he probably wanted the last records, but that usn-ä#t hgere the question it stated 2 days, but for that he needs to use ROW:NUMBER  by Partition