# using any condition other than the primary key in "where" clause on MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

i'm practicing on MySQL and i have a question about the "where" clause , why in MySQL the condition that comes after "where" should be in the primary key ? 
if i put any condition other than the primary key it will be an error !!

for example i have a table called "students" with 4 columns , first one is "stuid" and its the primary key
and there are "stuname" , "classroom" , "stuage" and these are the rest of the columns
why i can't say for example

`update students 
set stuname = 'sarah' 
where classroom = 46;`

and this is the error :

" Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect."

i tried to do what the messsage says but i didnt understand the part about "reconnect"

hence : i'm using MySQL on mac

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL error code: 1175 during UPDATE in MySQL Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench)

Answer (score 1):

we can use any key's with update. the issue may be with the IDE you are using.Kindly specify the **IDE and MySQL** version you are using.
or 
google about Turing off the safe mode in your IDE/MySQL.

**What is Safe Mode?**

it is used to prevent the unnecessary/accidentally updating a bunch of rows in a table.(*where clause with non-unique keys*)

to turn of the safe mode try

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
```

its safer to turning on the safe mode after use.

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
```