# Data not getting saved in database using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Im building blog app and im trying to store average rating in posts table with this function in  **PostController.php**.

```
public function avgRating ($avgRating) {
    $posts=DB::statement('UPDATE posts p
    SET p.avgRating=
        (SELECT ROUND(AVG(r.rating), 0)
        FROM ratings r
        WHERE p.id=r.rateable_id)');
        $posts = Post::all();
  }
```

Every other function that i created is saving data in database except this one. I tried to run sql query by itself in phpmyadmin and it works, its storing the average rating of each post in that table. Can anyone explain how do i write that function correctly in Laravel?

Comment: Could you try update instead of statement to check if it's doing something? ```dd(DB::update(<query>)```

Comment: @JorgeRodríguez i tried update and its not working either

Comment: So you're trying to update all the rows in the posts table, to store in the column posts.avgRating the average of the related ratings, is that right?

Comment: Your system is running in safe update mode. That means that you can't update unless you specify the rows to update. You  try to run **SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;** before your update. Can see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench

Comment: @JorgeRodríguez my bad for writing that im not trying to update them all. YES i am trying to update them all. i have 3 tables: users, posts, and ratings, when user logs in and he rates a post, value of rating goes to ratings table and i want that after other users rate some posts that average of each post gets stored inside table posts, in column average rating. so i can see average rating for each post.

Comment: @nacho In phpmyadmin says that sql safe updates is set to off

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i am not an expert in laravel, but i think you could deactivate the safe mode before, and activate it back again when you finish. You could try to do it in this way:

```
public function avgRating ($avgRating) {
    DB::statement("SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;");
    $posts=DB::statement('UPDATE posts p
    SET p.avgRating=
        (SELECT ROUND(AVG(r.rating), 0)
        FROM ratings r
        WHERE p.id=r.rateable_id)');
        $posts = Post::all();
    DB::statement("SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;");
  }
```