# mySQL Inserting values randomly from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table "people" with ("ID","PassportNo")

```
+----------+----------+
| booking  | passport |
+----------+----------+
|        1 |   873246 |
|        1 |   535654 |
|       2  |   123232 |
+----------+----------+

CREATE TABLE people(
    id INTEGER,
    passportno INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY (id, passportno),
);
```

And I have a table passenger with ("ticketno","booking","passportno")

```
+-----------+---------+------------+
| thicketno | booking | passportno |
+-----------+---------+------------+
| 134133434 |       1 | NULL       |
| 324214234 |       1 | NULL       |
+-----------+---------+------------+ 


CREATE TABLE passenger(
ticketno INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
booking INTEGER,
passportno INTEGER,
```

How can I add all "passportno" from "people" table to "passenger" table based on the booking?

I believe it should be something like:

`UPDATE passenger SET passportno = (SELECT passpotno FROM people where people.booking=passenger.booking`

but I get an error "you are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column"

UPDATE:

it works when I add `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0`; ńow the problem is that I get 'subquery returns more than one row' and when I use a join I get the same passport number for anyone with the same booking id, I'd like to have all the different passport numbers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL error code: 1175 during UPDATE in MySQL Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench)

Comment: Consider adding a column to "passenger" to number passports  within a booking . In sql-sever one can do it on the fly, but in MySql i guess you need a column to persit the number.

Comment: How can adding a column of passpoert numbers could be helpful?

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your tables miss the key to uniquely match the rows
Consider adding a column to "passenger" to number passports within a booking .

Demo MySql 8.0.

Data setup

```
create table people (booking int, passportno int);
insert people
values(1,873246)
,(1,535654)
,(2,123232);

create table passenger (thicketno int, booking int, passportno int, passpSeq int);
insert passenger
values (134133434, 1, NULL,NULL)
,(324214234, 1, NULL,NULL);
```

The query, set passpSeq first

```
UPDATE passenger
JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0) r
SET passpSeq=@rank:=@rank+1;
```

and now

```
UPDATE
  passenger p 
JOIN
  (  select booking, passportno, row_number() over(partition by booking order by passportno) rn
     from people  
  ) pp
       on p.booking = pp.booking and p.passpSeq=pp.rn
SET p.passportno = pp.passportno;
```

For older version you can emulate row_number() see http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `join`:

```
UPDATE passenger p JOIN
       people pp
       on p.booking = pp.booking
    SET p.passportno = pp.passpotno;
```

Comment: it works when I add `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;` but in that case I will get the same passport number for anyone with the same booking id, I'd like to have all the different passport numbers.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench)
you could for instance execute this command before updating your rows:

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
```