# MySQL Error Code: 1175 during UPDATE with a WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to update the `total` of `Payment` to the total of `price` from `Packages` where the transaction numbers are the same. However MySQL keeps giving me the error:

> Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.  To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.

Here is the command:

```
UPDATE Payment py
SET total = (SELECT SUM(price) FROM Package pk
             WHERE py.transactionNo = pk.transactionNo);
```

I would think that I am using a WHERE that uses a KEY column (`transactionNo` is the primary key for `Payment`). Am I simply writing this wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL error code: 1175 during UPDATE in MySQL Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench)

Comment: The error message tells you that you are not using a key column to update a single row from `py`. The `WHERE` clause is not part of the `UPDATE` query itself, but of a sub query

Comment: Is there any logic why you want to save a "total" that is a calculated field? We don't save that data.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli The initial value for total is 0, but once I add all the packages for a payment, I then want to update it with the total price of all these packages

Comment: @JJBeaudry I understand, my question is related about why indeed is that field necessary at all?

Comment: @LeandroBardelli Ideally I suppose it isn't necessary, but it is for a school project where I need "Interesting UPDATE statements". So if this query doesn't make sense because of not saving calculated fields I will just have to try something else

Comment: @JJBeaudry oh, sorry!!! I understand now. Definitely is interesting. Not applicable in real life except if you want to save and history of the value changes, but it's 100% fine. Sorry.

Comment: @LeandroBardelli No problem! What you are saying definitely makes sense in a real life application

Answer (score 2):

You have no a where condition for update..

In this case you could use a proper updated  with join using a subquery

```
UPDATE Payment py
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT pk.transactionNo, SUM(price) sum_price
    FROM Package pk
    GROUP BY pk.transactionNo
    WHERE py.transactionNo = pk.transactionNo
) t on  py.transactionNo = t.transactionNo

SET py.total =t.sum_price
```