# I'm trying to delete a data in row even t code was correct it is showing error:1175 "you are using safe update mode"

Tags: mysql

delete from `gov.msme.india`
where micro = 212014;
SELECT * FROM msme.`gov.msme.india`;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL error code: 1175 during UPDATE in MySQL Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update without specifying a primary key. You could disable safe update mode with the commande.

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
```

To be sure check what will modified by running a SELECT first.