# Deleting rows in SQL throws error. How to fix thar?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

```
DELETE FROM albums WHERE release_year IS NULL;
```

I am running this SQL Query to delete rows that have `release_year` as null, but this throws an error telling me that,

```
You are using safe update mode and trying to update a table without a where keyword
```

Comment: try using solutions from here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench

Comment: @P.Salmon what do you mean by triggers? I am just running this single command Btw.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your MySql session has the [safe-updates](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_safe-updates) option set. This means it can't update or delete records without specifying a key (ex. `primary key`) in the `where` clause. If you don't want to specify the key in the `where` clause then executes the below code first and then try executing your query.

`SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;`

Comment: Ok so we can't update/delete without primary key. Got it.

Comment: It seems this works too: `DELETE FROM albums WHERE release_year IS NULL LIMIT 10;`  This will delete the first 10 records.  Change 10 to a higher number to delete more records.