# I am getting this error after applying this query

Tags: sql

> Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to
> update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.  To disable
> safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and
> reconnect.

```
DELETE e1
FROM employeedetail AS e1
INNER JOIN employeedetail AS e2 ON e1.email = e2.email AND e1.id < e2.id;
```

i tried this

Comment: you didn't specify what to delete try using where

Comment: You should tell us what RDBMS you use (even if we can guess it's mysql). The error message is extremely clear : did you forget to add a WHERE to your query or is it intended ? You could also replace your INNER JOIN by a WHERE doing the same thing, or add a dummy WHERE but does not restrict anything, or disable safe mode...

Comment: Did you **read** that error message?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 1):

Are you using MySQL？This error is usually caused by MySQL's Safe Update Mode.When secure update mode is enabled, the UPDATE statement must include a WHERE clause, and the primary key or unique index column of the table must be used in the WHERE clause.

You can Disable secure update mode.`SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;` or add the appropriate WHERE clause in your UPDATE statement.

You can refer to this article [MySQL error code: 1175 during UPDATE in MySQL Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11448068/mysql-error-code-1175-during-update-in-mysql-workbench)