# Mysql update query limit not working if i join two tables

Tags: mysql, sql-update

In MYSQL if i set limit in update while joining two tables it show

> ERROR 1221 (HY000): Incorrect usage of UPDATE and LIMIT

```
update 
       order_product_mapping as opm, 
       order_details as od, 
       product as p 
   set fullfillment='Y' 
 where 
       p.product_id=opm.product_id 
       AND od.order_id=opm.order_id 
       AND od.order_id=100 
       AND p.product_id=1 limit 1;
```

My table schema is 
order_details table

```
CREATE TABLE `order_details` (
  `order_id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `amount` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_status` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `company_order_id` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`order_id`)
)
```

Product table

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `product_id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `product_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_amount` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product_status` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `company_product_id` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`)
)
```

order_product_mapping

```
CREATE TABLE `order_product_mapping` (
  `product_id` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `order_id` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fulfillment` char(1) DEFAULT 'N'
)
```

I will get company_order_id and company_product_id as input so that i made a update query to change the status of my fulfillment in order_product_mapping. If add limit in the query it show an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this post for an explanation of your error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4291851/1073631

I do think I've found a work-around/hack.  Join the order_product_mapping table on itself and create a row number.  Using row number = 1 should work the same way as LIMIT 1:

```
UPDATE order_product_mapping opm
  JOIN (SELECT *, @rowNum:=@rowNum+1 rn FROM order_product_mapping JOIN (SELECT @rowNum:= 0) r)
    as opm2 ON opm.product_id = opm2.product_id and opm.order_id = opm2.order_id
  JOIN product p ON p.product_id=opm.product_id AND p.product_id=1
  JOIN order_details as od ON od.order_id=opm.order_id 
SET opm.fulfillment = 'Y'
where od.order_id=100 
And rn = 1;
```

And some sample Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/03f12/1

Comment: Thank you @Sgeddes . Those link are really helped me lot